# Why tkinter multiple window GUI not working properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I am creating multiple window GUI using tkinter.
I did not receive any errors. First window runs successfully but when I clicked the button the second window doesn't run.

I don't understand where there's an error,
and if I pack `Entry` widget and `Button`s they don't show in window.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pywhatkit
import pyautogui


class automation(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("842x510")
        self.configure(bg="#ffffff")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.container = container = tk.Frame(self, background="#ffffff")
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        container.configure(background="#ffffff")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainWindow, SecondWindow):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

        self.show_frame('MainWindow')

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        if page_name not in self.frames:
            self.frames[page_name] = page_name(self.container, self)

        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


def btn_clicked():
    print("Button Clicked")
```

Code for first window.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#ffffff", height=510, width=391, bd=0, 
        highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left')
        self.background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.background_img, anchor="nw")

        self.img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img1.png")
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self, image=self.img1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SecondWindow),
                            relief="flat")

        self.b1.place(x=392, y=100, width=348, height=62)
        self.b1.pack(padx=10, pady=125)
        self.b1.pack()

        # creating third button

        self.img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img3.png")
        self.b3 = tk.Button(self, image=self.img3, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, 
                            command=btn_clicked, relief="flat")

        self.b3.place(x=392, y=200, width=348, height=62)
        self.b3.pack(padx=10, pady=0)
        self.b3.pack()
        self.canvas.pack()

def send(num, msg, hour, minute):
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{num}", msg, hour, minute, 36)
    print("hello")
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Code for second window:

```
class SecondWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        a = tk.StringVar()
        b = tk.StringVar()
        c = tk.IntVar()
        d = tk.IntVar()
        self.controller = controller
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#ffffff", height=510, width=842, bd=0, 
                                highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left')

        # set image in background
        self.background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="background2.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.background_img, anchor="nw")

        # enter a number
        self.entry1_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox1.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(570, 112, image=self.entry1_img)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=a)
        self.entry1.place(x=423, y=90, width=280, height=45)
        #self.entry1.pack()

        # enter a massage

        self.entry2_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox2.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(570, 225, image=self.entry2_img)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=b)

        self.entry2.place(x=423, y=203, width=280, height=45)
        #self.entry2.pack()

        # enter a time -> Hour
        self.entry3_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox3.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(470, 329, image=self.entry3_img)

        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self, bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=c)

        self.entry3.place(x=423, y=312, width=80.0, height=35)
        #self.entry3.pack()

        # minute
        self.entry4_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox4.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(676, 329, image=self.entry4_img)

        self.entry4 = tk.Entry(self, bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=d)

        self.entry4.place(x=630, y=312, width=80.0, height=35)
        #self.entry4.pack()

        # Go home
        self.img4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img4.png")
        self.b4 = tk.Button(self, image=self.img4, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainWindow), relief="flat")

        self.b4.place(x=418, y=400, width=100, height=37)
        #self.b4.pack()

        # Send message
        self.img5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img5.png")
        self.b5 = tk.Button(self, image=self.img5, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            command=lambda: send(a.get(), b.get(), c.get(), d.get()), 
                            relief="flat")

        self.b5.place(x=642, y=400, width=100, height=37)
        #self.b5.pack()
        self.canvas.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = automation()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Thanks for providing the code that produces your error. In future, please try and provide the code as a [mre], so that someone can copy, paste and run it without having to edit the code (such as editing out the .png files in your code). Thanks!

Comment: You should also leave out `import`s for packages you're not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SecondWindow),` is passing the class id as argument so `page_name` is not being found.

suggest

```
command=lambda: controller.show_frame('SecondWindow')
```